Unit Test ServiceClass1 has challenge in Mocking Session, SessionBag in .Net 8.0 class Library Project Target 4.7.1 and .Net 8.0
Unit Test ServiceClass1 that calls "GetCurrentUserIsImpersonating" method of the "HttpContextWrapper" class which calls the "IsImpersonating" extension method in the "UserIdentityExtensions" static class, which relies on the SessionBag.Current.Impersonator value. it call TrGetMember in SessionBag and exit when execute Current.Session != null. Added set here    private static ISession Session
Removed interval in set if Public static dynamic Current.
The .Net Framework 4.7.1 Unit test pass but the .Net core 8.0 unit test fails becuase challenge to mock the SessionBag.Current.
The followig code is the unit test mocking part
but it exit from unit test when execute  SessionBag.Current.Session = mockSession.Object; give this in output.
The program '[26852] testhost.exe' has exited with code 3221225477 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
Please advise.
**Unit Test Mocking Part**
var mockHttpContextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();

// Create a DefaultHttpContext (this will automatically have Request, Response, etc.)
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();

// Create HttpRequest and configure its properties
var request = httpContext.Request;
request.Scheme = "https";
request.Host = new HostString("www.test.com");
request.Path = "/somepath";
request.QueryString = QueryString.Empty;
request.Method = "GET"; // Set the HTTP method


// Create a ClaimsIdentity and add claims (including the ones IsImpersonating may check)
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "TestUser"));
claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("ImpersonatorClaim", "SomeValue"));

// Create a ClaimsPrincipal with the mocked ClaimsIdentity
var claimsPrincipal = new Mock<ClaimsPrincipal>();
claimsPrincipal.Setup(p => p.HasClaim(It.Is<Predicate<Claim>>(pred =>
    pred(new Claim("ImpersonatorClaim", "SomeValue"))))).Returns(true);

// Assign the mocked ClaimsPrincipal to HttpContext.User
httpContext.User = claimsPrincipal.Object;

// Set up the HttpContextAccessor mock to return the httpContext
mockHttpContextAccessor.Setup(a => a.HttpContext).Returns(httpContext);

var mockSession = new Mock<ISession>();
var mockPrincipal = new Mock<IPrincipal>();

// Setup mock session behavior
mockSession.Setup(s => s.TryGetValue(It.IsAny<string>(), out It.Ref<byte[]>.IsAny))
    .Returns(true)
    .Callback((string key, out byte[] value) =>
    {
        if (key == "Impersonator")
        {
            value = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }; // Example byte array
        }
        else
        {
            value = null;
        }
    });

// Initialize SessionBag with the mock session
SessionBag.Current = new SessionBag();
var sessionProperty = typeof(SessionBag).GetProperty("Session", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
if (sessionProperty != null && sessionProperty.CanWrite)
{
    sessionProperty.SetValue(null, mockSession.Object);
}

if (SessionBag.Current == null)
{
    SessionBag.Current = new SessionBag();  // Initialize it properly
}

// Mock the session object
var mockSession = new Mock<ISession>();
mockSession.Setup(s => s.TryGetValue(It.IsAny<string>(), out It.Ref<byte[]>.IsAny)).Returns(true);

// Set the mock session to the SessionBag
SessionBag.Current.Session = mockSession.Object;

// Act
var result = mockPrincipal.Object.IsImpersonating();

HttpContextWrapper.Configure(mockHttpContextAccessor.Object, "");



**HttpContextWrapper class**

#if NET8_0_OR_GREATER
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
#else
using System;
using System.Web;
#endif

namespace Tools
{
    public static class HttpContextWrapper
    {
#if NET8_0_OR_GREATER
        private static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor m_httpContextAccessor;
        private static string WebRootPath { get; }

        public static void Configure(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, string webRootPath)
        {
            m_httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
        public static bool CheckAccessorIsNull()
        {
            return m_httpContextAccessor == null;
        }
        public static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_httpContextAccessor != null)
                {
                    return m_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        public static bool CurrentUserIsLoggedIn()
        {
            return Current != null;
        }
        public static string GetImpersonatorName()
        {
            return Current.User.Identity.ImpersonatorName().ToUpper();
        }
        public static bool CurrentUserIsAuthenticated()
        {
            if (Current != null)
            {
                return Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool GetCurrentUserIsImpersonating()
        {
            if (Current != null)
            {
                return Current.User.IsImpersonating();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static string GetCurrentUser()
        {
            return Current.User.Identity.Name.ToUpper();
        }

        public static bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            return Current.User.IsInRole(role);
        }

        public static string GetFile(string filePath)
        {
            return string.Concat(WebRootPath, filePath);
        }

        public static string GetBaseUrl()
        {
            var uri = string.Empty;
            var port = Current.Request.Host.Port;

            if (port != null)
            {
                uri = Current.Request.Host.ToString().Replace(port.ToString(), string.Empty);
            }
            else
            {
                uri = Current.Request.Host.ToString();
            }

            return uri;
        }
#else
        public static bool CurrentUserIsLoggedIn()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current != null;
        }

        public static string GetImpersonatorName()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.ImpersonatorName().ToUpper();
        }

        public static bool CurrentUserIsAuthenticated()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }

        public static bool GetCurrentUserIsImpersonating()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.User.IsImpersonating();
        }

        public static string GetCurrentUser()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToUpper();
        }

        public static bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(role);
        }

        public static string GetFile(string filePath)
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath);
        }
#endif
    }
}

**UserIdentityExtensions**


  public static class UserIdentityExtensions
   {
       public static bool IsImpersonating(this IPrincipal principal)
       {
           if (SessionBag.Current.Impersonator == null)
           {
               return false;
           }

           var impersonator = SessionBag.Current.Impersonator as string;
           if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(impersonator))
           {
               return false;
           }

           return true;
       }
       public static string ImpersonatorName(this IIdentity identity)
       {
           if (SessionBag.Current.Impersonator == null)
           {
               return string.Empty;
           }

           var impersonator = SessionBag.Current.Impersonator as string;
           if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(impersonator))
           {
               return string.Empty;
           }

           return impersonator.ToUpper();
       }
   }

**SessionBag class**

namespace Helper
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Dynamic;
    using System.Web;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    [Serializable]
    public class SessionBag : DynamicObject
    {
        private static SessionBag current;
        static SessionBag()
        {
            current = new SessionBag();
        }
        public static dynamic Current
        {
            get
            {
                return current;
            }

            internal set
            {
                current = value;
            }
        }
#if NET8_0_OR_GREATER
        private static ISession Session
        {
            get
            {
                var session = Current.Session;
                return session;
            }
        }

#else
        private static HttpSessionStateBase Session
        {
            get
            {
                var session = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session;
                return new HttpSessionStateWrapper(session);
            }
        }
#endif
#if NET8_0_OR_GREATER
        public object this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                Session.TryGetValue(name,out byte[] val);
                return val;
            }

            set
            {
                Session.Set(name, (byte[])value);
            }
        }
#else
        public object this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                return Session[name];
            }

            set
            {
                Session[name] = value;
            }
        }
#endif
        public static void Remove(string key)
        {
            Session.Remove(key);
        }
        public static void Add(string key, object value)
        {
#if NET8_0_OR_GREATER
            Session.Set(key, (byte[])value);
#else
            Session.Add(key, value);
#endif
        }
        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
#if NET8_0_OR_GREATER
            if (Current.Session != null)
            {
                Session.TryGetValue(binder.Name,out byte[] val);
                result = val;
#else
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
              {
                result = Session[binder.Name];
#endif
            }
            else
            {
                result = null;
            }

            return true;
        }
        public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
        {
            this[binder.Name] = value;
            return true;
        }
        public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
        {
            try
            {
#if NET8_0_OR_GREATER
                Session.TryGetValue(binder.Name,out byte[] val);
                result=val; 
#else
                result = Session[binder.Name];

#endif
                if (result == null)
                {
                    result = args[0];
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return base.TryInvokeMember(binder, args, out result);
            }
        }
        public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
        {
            var keys = new List<string>();
            foreach (var key in Session.Keys)
            {
                keys.Add(key.ToString());
            }

            return keys;
        }
        public override bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            return base.TryConvert(binder, out result);
        }
    }
}





Please edit the post by removing (and adding) code so that the problem is small enough that the essence is understandable by other people, as well as reproducible.

The provided code doesn't compile. Please provide a minimal, reproducible example.

The problem is Session implementation  is different between .Net Framework and .Net core 8.0. The unit test work for .Net 4.7.1, but the unit test same code is not working for .Net core 8.0. The reason is storing different type of value like string, string[], object, null. In .Net Framework it works with any issue but in .Net Core it expect byte[] and need to serialize and deserialize data to respective type. the code is written for 4.7.1 but targeted to work .n core 8.0
